# what happens when we restart a running CA server container?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

if i restart my running CA server container will my network stop working after restart and will i loose any data ? is it okay to do this or not ?

```
I just don't want to loose any data because my network is in pro environment.
```

Answer (score 1):

[`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) preserves the container, so no data is lost.

---

What you need to watch out for is the [`docker rm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/) command or the [`docker-compose down`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) command.
These commands evaporate the container. If container information is important, you can back up an existing container to an image using the [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) command.